# my bottom navigation view isnt visible even after coding correctly,

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have coded for the bottom navigation view but it doesn't work for my current project however if I use the same code in another project it is visible.
Also the default background of my activity comes as black for my current project.

Here's my XML file:

[image: My XML file looks like this]

And here are my menu's content

[image: And the Bottom Menu looks like this]

Comment: Try to rebuild your project If every thing is fine or share your code for debugging

Comment: android:layout_height="56dp" try setting height and test again instead of wrap content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add the design support library to your app-level `build.gradle` file. For Exemple:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Then click the `Sync Now` button. Also, you need to complete other attributes in your `activity_h2.xml` like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       design:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

PS: The `android:id="@+id/navigation"` is important to listening for events on the bottom navigation in your `h2.java`